# Container (podman/docker) volume nfs from window

Tags: containers, docker-volume, podman

On window i have a network drive A: which map \company.local\PARTAGE

I tried to do a NFS mount to create a volume for my container.

First i have created a volume:

```
podman volume create --driver local --opt type=nfs4 --opt o=addr=192.168.0.123,rw --opt device=:/volume1/DATA  MOUNTNFS
```

And after i tried to start my container like this

```
podman run -it -v MOUNTNFS:/appl/DATA_MOUNT test:test bash
```

But i get this error with type nfs4 or nfs :

> Error: preparing container
> 1168799066deaddfa8ef2ac97722b202a1845973804d3620ec58c265d2c903f1 for
> attach: mounting volume MOUNTNFS for container
> 1168799066deaddfa8ef2ac97722b202a1845973804d3620ec58c265d2c903f1:
> mount:
> /home/user/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes/MOUNTNFS/_data:
> permission denied.
> dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

i use /volume1/DATA because on another machine (redhat) on the network, I had managed to mount on this same data by editing the /etc/fstab and putting this `192.168.0.123:/volume1/DATA  /data nfs defaults 0 0`

So i tried to translate this into container volume from windows

the Mount I wish to reach is accessible via Windows Explorer following several URLs:

- \192.168.0.123\data\
- \company.local\PARTAGE\DATA
- \dc1\PARTAGE\DATA